# Correct Google analytics api for my project

Tags: c#, google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api, google-api-dotnet-client

We are busy with a project where we want to show our customers their popularity rating on our site.  Each customer has pages on our sites and we want to use the visits for those pages in Google Analytics to gauge their popularity.

What we though we would do was to query the Google analytics API for the page visits over a period of time for a specific page(this will be dynamic depending on the page). When we then get the result back which we will use in our own design and layout.

It seems to me the [Reporting Api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/) is for more complex iterations. We have not been able to find a more simple version of this API.  Is there another way to access this API.

Environment is asp.net C#

Comment: Welcome to stack.  I have tried to tweek your question a little you may want to read this before asking your next question.    https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask   Good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three apis for requesting data from the Google analytics api.

- Real-time api returns the last five minutes of data give or take.
- Core reporting api V3 this is the V3 of the google analytics api.
- Reporting api v4 This is the latest version of the api.

While the Reporting api mak seam complex to you it is the only option you have for requesting data out of google analytics.  I suggest you check the documentation [C# samples](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/samples) for how to use the API.

A simple method for requesting data would look like this

```
// Create the DateRange object.
DateRange dateRange = new DateRange() { StartDate = "2015-06-15", EndDate = "2015-06-30" };

// Create the Metrics object.
Metric sessions = new Metric { Expression = "ga:sessions", Alias = "Sessions" };

//Create the Dimensions object.
Dimension browser = new Dimension { Name = "ga:browser" };

// Create the ReportRequest object.
// Create the ReportRequest object.
ReportRequest reportRequest = new ReportRequest
{
    ViewId = "XXXX",
    DateRanges = new List<DateRange>() { dateRange },
    Dimensions = new List<Dimension>() { browser },
    Metrics = new List<Metric>() { sessions }
};

List<ReportRequest> requests = new List<ReportRequest>();
requests.Add(reportRequest);

// Create the GetReportsRequest object.
GetReportsRequest getReport = new GetReportsRequest() { ReportRequests = requests };

// Call the batchGet method.
GetReportsResponse response = analyticsreporting.Reports.BatchGet(getReport).Execute();
```

I recomend that you use service account authentication.  I have a sample for that here [ServiceAccount.cs](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/blob/master/Samples/Google%20Analytics%20Reporting%20API/v4/ServiceAccount.cs)

**Warning**

There are several quotas in with the google analytics api one of them means that you can max make 10000 requests per view.    This being the view that your data is being inserted into.   Unless you cache your data you are going to have issues with this quota if you have a busy website.  There is no way to extend this quota even throwing money at google will not get them to extend it.

Comment: Great thanks, I am only getting an error trying to authenticate: "Unrecognized credential type" I assume something wrong with the JSON file downloaded? How do I confirm that is correct? Also how do I know what to put inside the Scopes Array string? Thanks for all the help so far.

Comment: Actually got past above issue but still after the BatchGet Call getting this error: "Google.GoogleApiException: 'Google.Apis.Requests.RequestError
Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. " I created a service account credential and downloaded a txt file which I copied into a Json file. Also another question: what exactly should come in the ViewId = "XXXX" ?